# htaccess rewrite old url to new seo url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have today some URLs like this:

http://www.mydomain/nyhet?nid=235-url-name.html

I'll like to have htaccess convert to seo URLs in this way:

http://www.mydomain/nyhet/235-url-name.html

This i my code in htaccess today:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.se [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.se/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?sida=$1 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^nyhet/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)\.html$ /index.php?nyhet=$1
```

Today `/nyhet/124-seo.html` works fine in my system. But the old url with `/nyhet?nid=124-seo.html` does not redirect to `/nyhet/124-seo.html`

I try to add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.se [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.se/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)ä(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)å(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ö(.*)$ /$1o$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ä(.*)$ /$1A$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Å(.*)$ /$1A$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ö(.*)$ /$1O$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nid=(.*?)($|&) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?nyhet /nyhet/%1? [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?sida=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nyhet/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)\.html$ /index.php?nyhet=$1
```

But the server error says: `www.mydomain.se redirected you too many times`

Any idea?

Comment: with this htaccess your not telling apache to redirect, ofc it do not do that

Comment: edit your question and write what you tried, its more readable

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro
I have edit the question now

Comment: you don not need the second RewriteEnting On

Comment: You need to do things in the right order. `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$` matches the relevant parts of `http://www.mydomain/nyhet?nid=235-url-name.html`, so your currently second RewriteRule will rewrite this to `/index.php?sida=$1` already.

Comment: @misorude I have updated my code and try to change order. But still the same problem.

Comment: If a RewriteRule does not specify a new query string, then the old one will be appended automatically - so `RewriteRule ^/?nyhet /nyhet/$1 [L,R=301]` will still append the `?nid=235-url-name.html` to the final rewrite target, and with that the RewriteCond checking for that query string parameter matches again when that rewritten request gets checked again in the next round. Try and append a question mark, `RewriteRule ^/?nyhet /nyhet/$1? [L,R=301]` - that should prevent the original query string from getting added.

Comment: And if that’s not it (such issues aren’t always easy to debug “dry”, by just seeing the code), then I would suggest you go enable rewrite logging, and check what’s actually going on.

Comment: @misorude i change to `RewriteRule ^/?nyhet /nyhet/$1? [L,R=301]` and the redirect all news to mydomain.se/nyhet/ , no seo url added

Comment: `$N` (here: `$1`) refers back to grouped matches of the RewriteRule pattern - but you don’t have any in there. Instead, you want to access what your previous RewriteCond captured - which means you need to use `%N` instead (here: `%1`)

Comment: @misorude Do I understand right now that you mean I should change $1 to %1?

Comment: Yes. There is no $1 available, because your _rule_ did not group anything. You want to access the value the _condition_ captured, and accessing those is done using `%N`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: @misorude
I have change the code now. But now its redirect to `http://www.mydomain.se/nyhet/123-seo.html?nid=123-seo.html`

Comment: And did you add the trailing `?` to the replacement URL, that I talked about earlier, or is that gone again now?

Comment: @misorude Correct, i have miss the `?`and now its works fine. Thank you! Last question: In this code i also need to change `åäö` to ´aao´. Do you know how?

Comment: That is not a totally trivial thing, it usually involves replacing one found character, and then sending it through the whole process again, “looping” until none of those characters is found any more. https://www.geoffhayward.eu/2014/04/character-replace-with-apache-module-mod-rewrite has a pretty extensive explanation of how that works.